# How to graph requests per second from web log file using R

Tags: r

I'm trying to graph request per second using our apache log files.
I've massaged the log down to a simple listing of the timestamps, one entry per request.

04:02:28
04:02:28
04:02:28
04:02:29
...

I can't quite figure out how to get R to recognize as time and aggregate to per second.
Thanks for any help

Comment: As a side note, you may be interested in [Logstalgia](http://code.google.com/p/logstalgia/) for some fun visualizations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that since you already have time-stamps at one-second granularity, all you need to do is do a frequency-count of the time-stamps and plot the frequencies *in the original time-order*. Say `timeStamps` is your array of time-stamps, then you would do:

```
plot(c( table( timeStamps ) ) )
```

I'm assuming you want to plot the log-messages in each one-second interval over a certain period. Also I'm assuming that the HMS time-stamps are within one day. Note that the `table` function produces a frequency-count of its argument.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me, I'm new to R, so was having some troubles with getting the data in, I'm still not quite sure what c() and table() did but I'm happy. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

The lubridate package makes working with dates and time very easy.

Here is an example, using the hms() function of lubridate.  hms  converts a character string into a data frame with separate columns for hours, minutes and seconds.  There are similar functions for myd (month-day-year), dmy (day-month-year), ms (minutes-seconds)... you get the point.

```
library(lubridate)
data <- c("04:02:28", "04:02:28", "04:02:28", "04:02:29")
times <- hms(data)
times$second

[1] 28 28 28 29
```

At this point, times is a straight-forward data frame, and you can isolate any column you wish:

```
str(times)

Classes 'period' and 'data.frame':  4 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ year  : num  0 0 0 0
 $ month : num  0 0 0 0
 $ day   : num  0 0 0 0
 $ hour  : num  4 4 4 4
 $ minute: num  2 2 2 2
 $ second: num  28 28 28 29
```

Comment: I couldn't get my data to be in a happy format for cms() to work. I read the data in using data <- c(read.table("timestamps.log"))  But each time I tried hms(data) it gave me an error that attribute must be the same length as the vector

Comment: Maybe you can use dput() and paste a small extract from your data file in the question above, so we can see what is unique about your format?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure, how to make this correctly, but this should be one possible way and maybe helps you.

1. Instead of strings, get the data as UNIX timestamps from the database that denote the number of seconds from 1970-01-01.
2. Use hist(data) to plot a histogram for example. Or you may use `melt` command from `reshape2` package and use `cast` for creating a data frame, where one column is the timestamp and another column determines the number of transactions at that time.
3. Use `as.POSIXlt(your.unix.timestamps, origin="1970-01-01", tz="GMT")` to convert the timestamps to R understandable datetime structures.
4. Then add labels to the plot using the data from point 3 using `format`.

Here's an example:

```
# original data
data.timestamps = c(1297977452, 1297977452, 1297977453, 1297977454, 1297977454, 1297977454, 1297977455, 1297977455)
data.unique.timestamps = unique(data.timestamps)

# get the labels
data.labels = format(as.POSIXlt(data.unique.timestamps, origin="1970-01-01", tz="GMT"), "%H:%M:%S")

# plot the histogram without axes
hist(data.timestamps, axes=F)

# add axes manually
axis(2)
axis(1, at=unique(data.timestamps), labels=data.labels)
```

--
Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, I like this solution too. I was able to run your example but was receiving an error on not able to convert to class POSIXlt. I think it is because when I read in from file it converted to scientific notation