# Requests per second, per hour, per day out of a time series

Tags: python, r, time, ggplot2

I am relatively new to R, and it's the first time I am trying to use it to actually analyze some data. The problem is the following: I have a CSV file containing a log of the number of requests served a given system in the following form:

```
# Unix timestamp, number of requests
1354810257,241624
1354810258,244759
1354810259,245307
1354810260,248961
```

At the moment the file contains the information relative to a week period. Now I need to obtain a graph showing how many requests per second, per hour and per day the system is able to sustain.

Comment: The number of requests is actually a monotonically increasing sequence.

Comment: If that is true then an aggregation by second, hour and date should be possible using difference between starting and ending values. @nopper needs to provide a better example for testing and needs to clarify the underlying meaning of his data..

Comment: The entire CSV file was extracted from a Graphite server monitoring a cluster of nodes. The number of requests here represents the number of items processed by the cluster itself. Imagine them to be number of HTTP requests and the cluster to be an HTTP server. What I need is something similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034513/how-to-graph-requests-per-second-from-web-log-file-using-r with the only difference that I need statitistics per day, per hour and per seconds in order to understand the performance of the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it using Python and matplotlib. The code is something similar to this:

```
import csv
from pylab import *
from itertools import groupby

def by_hour(value):
    return value[0] // 3600

def plot_data_for(data, map_, reduce_):
    keys = []
    values = []
    for k,v in groupby(data, key=map_):
        keys.append(k)
        values.append(reduce_(v))
    return (keys, values)

times = []
requests = []
reader = csv.reader(open("results.csv"))

for row in reader:
    times.append(int(row[0]))
    requests.append(int(row[1]))

increments = map(lambda x: x[1] - x[0], zip(requests, requests[1:] + [requests[-1]]))
plot(*plot_data_for(zip(times, increments), by_hour, lambda values: sum(map(lambda x: x[1], values))))
```